# Reading multiple values from xml and updating only single value in xml

Tags: c#, xml

I developed a code to update an existing xml.

The xml contains too many information but I need only few. So I made some changes.

The existing XML looks like

```
<Parent><Name>P_Im</Name>
<Caption>First order</Caption>
<Category>TestResults</Category>
<Values>
<Value>43</Value><Value>33</Value><Value>37</Value><Value>39</Value>
</Values>
</Parameter>
```

And I need to read only the **first value** tag which shows the **value 43** and few changes on xml.
I wrote the following code,

```
var im = document.Descendants("Parameter").Where(a =>a.Element("Name").Value == "P_Im").FirstOrDefault();                
string IM_val = im.Element("Values").Value;              
string final = "<Information><Name>P_CIm</Name><Caption> ONE</Caption><Value>" + IM_val + "</Value><Color/><Range/><Status/></Information>";
```

This code generates the result as following,

```
<Information>
<Name>P_CIm</Name>
<Caption> ONE</Caption>
<Value>4333739</Value>
</Information>";
```

But I want my result as,

```
<Information>
<Name>P_CIm</Name>
<Caption> ONE</Caption>
<Value>43</Value>
</Information>";
```

I see that a small logic should be used here, as I am beginner suggest me some ideas.

Thanks in advance for help and support.

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting the "Values" element and returning the text of all it's child elements.

Instead of:

```
string IM_val = im.Element("Values").Value;
```

Use:

```
string IM_val = im.Element("Values").Element("Value").Value;
```